# Simple queries take very long

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

When I execute a query for the first time in DBeaver it can take up to 10-15 seconds to display the result. In SQLDeveloper those queries only take a fraction of that time.

For example:
Simple "select column1 from table1" statement

DBeaver: 2006ms, 
SQLDeveloper: 306ms

Example 2 (other way around; so theres no server-side caching):
Simple "select column1 from table2" statement

SQLDeveloper: 252ms,
DBeaver: 1933ms

DBeavers status box says:

1. Fetch resultset
2. Discover attribute column1
3. Find attribute column1
4. Late bind attribute colummn1

2, 3 and 4 use most of the query execution time.

I'm using oracle 11g, SQLDeveloper 4.1.1.19 and DBeaver 3.5.8.

See http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1870

What could be the cause?

Comment: I'm not asking to fix that bug, if it is one. I am asking whether anyone has experienced it as well and if anyone knows a cause.

Comment: That's not a programming question. Use chat if you want to discuss this.

Comment: I think I am allowed to ask a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers". No problem if you disagree.

Comment: SQL Developer only fetches the first 50 (or 100?) rows of a result. Maybe DBeaver fetches all of them? How many rows does your result have in total?

Comment: I tried to change sqldeveloper to 100, like dbeaver, but the query is still about as fast as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBeaver looks up some metadata related to objects in your query.

On an Oracle DB, it queries catalog tables such as

- SYS.ALL_ALL_TABLES / SYS.ALL_OBJECTS - only once after connection, for the first query you execute
- SYS.ALL_TAB_COLS / SYS.ALL_INDEXES / SYS.ALL_CONSTRAINTS / ... - I believe each time you query a table not used before.

Version 3.6.10 introduced an option to enable/disable a hint used in those queries. Disabling the hint made a huge difference for me. The option is in the Oracle Properties tab of the connection edit dialog. Have a look at [issue 360 on dbeaver's github](https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/issues/360) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! I saw the ticket yesterday, but since it was targeted for release 3.7 I though I'd have to wait. Great that it's finally been addressed.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get insight is to perfom the [database trace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/sqltrace.htm#PFGRF010)

Perform few time the query to eliminate the caching effect.

Than repeat in both IDEs following steps

**activate the trace**

```
ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = test_IDE_xxxx;

 alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12'; /* binds + waits */
```

Provide the xxxx to identify the test. You will see this string as a part of the trace file name.

Use level 12 to see the wait events and bind variables.

**run the query**

**close the conenction**

This is important to not trace other things.

Examine the two trace files to see:

- what statements were performed
- what number of rows was fetched
- what time was elapsed in DB
- for the rest of the time the client (IDE) is responsible

**This should provide you enough evidence to claim if one IDE behaves different than other or if simple the DB statements issued are different.**